# Why I'm getting Property does not exist... if I use a TypeScript union type in another file?

Tags: typescript, types

I'm exporting a type named `AsyncOptions` in the following way:

```js
// file: interfaces.ts
import { ClassProvider, FactoryProvider, ModuleMetadata } from '@nestjs/common/interfaces';

export type AsyncOptions = Pick<ClassProvider, 'useClass'> |
  (Pick<ModuleMetadata, 'imports'> & Pick<FactoryProvider, 'useFactory' | 'inject'>);
```

If I try to use properties, TypeScript **run just fine in the same file**:

```js
// file: interfaces.ts

// ...
const opts: AsyncOptions = {
  imports: [],
  useFactory: () => ({}),
};

if (options.useFactory) { } // OK here
```

However, if I try to use the same **in another file I get an error**:

> error TS2339: Property 'imports' does not exist on type 'AsyncOptions'.

```js
// file: providers.ts

import { AsyncOptions } from './interfaces'; 

public static factory(options: AsyncOptions): DynamicModule {
   if (options.useFactory) { } // KO here, error TS2339
}
```

Comment: `Pick<ClassProvider, 'useClass'>` <--- this type wouldn't have an `imports` property, hence the whole union does not have it as well. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggziAdgYwPJmASwPaLlAXigG8oBXOCAYQBsBDOOALijmACdNEBzKAXygAfElEwBbMNnbBmURGTEAjCO34BuAFAaAZmRRZcUbQAo67bi3hI0GHHgCULAG7ZMAExIaoUM9wB04pLScBp8QA

Comment: "run just fine in the same file" --- are you sure?

Comment: @zerkms I'm quite sure... I get the error on every property of AsyncOptions, not only useClass or imports.

Comment: It is expected that you get an error (on every property): I explained why and provided a link with an example. Why do you think it runs just fine in the other file?

Comment: So union type is like "you can only check for common members"? I looked at here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types where there is an example about `Bird` and `Fish` and explain how to solve the problem, but I think is not applicable in my case. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Basically - yes, if you don't reduce the union to one of its member via a type guard - then all your interactions with the value must be compatible with every member of a union.

Comment: Please try to produce a [mcve]; since it relies on multiple files, could you maybe demonstrate via stackblitz or codepen or other web IDE?  Good luck!